# Installing VMWARE ESXi 5.5 in VMWARE 9 Workstation

Tags: memory, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

I have to install VMWARE ESXi 5.5 as a Virtual machine on VMWARE 9 workstation. VMWARE 9 workstation is installed on windows 10 (64 bit OS). This is like nested virtualization.

However the virtual machines that will be running under VMWARE ESXi 5.5 will require 4 GB of RAM (64 bit OS). For testing purposes I will run one VM under ESXi with 4 GB of RAM. I have allocated 9GB of RAM to this ESXi 5.5 which is running as VM . Now when I give 9GB of RAM , VMWARE 9 gives me warning like this

```
32-bit host operating systems will be unable to power on virtual machines with more than 8GB of RAM.
```

Can someone please tell me what exactly this means? Is there anything I should be caring ? Please help and clarfiy

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VMware ESX(I) is a a bare metal virtualization application. It does not install inside VMware Workstation. It installs directly on a machine and replace the operating system on that machine

Comment: For those like us who dont have bare metal server how would they practice ESXi ? VMWARE community has already published KBs on how to install ESXi under vmware workstation.

Comment: Please follow this guide from vmware https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2034803

Comment: It is only for testing and not supported in a production environment  which is why my comment. The article is quite old and VMware Workstation V9 is long out of support as well. However, please let me know if you would like me to delete my answer

Comment: The article was last updated on 9/25/2018. :)

Comment: I would be glad if you answer my question about the warning message. Thanks

Comment: By default, you can only run 32-bit virtual machines in ESXi.  This addresses your requirement above  to run 64-bit machines .... This also where I saw the point about production which was not evident originally ...
VMware does not support running nested ESXi/ESX servers in production environments. For more information,